# Using GPL library in my own Apache library

Tags: apache-2.0, agpl-3.0

I have a GPL library and an Apache-licensed library. I want to use the GPL library in my Apache library and for the Apache library to stay Apache. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of, but probably not the way you want.

It is OK if a software contains components under different libraries, for example if the the software contains your Apache-2.0 code and (A)GPL-3.0 code. However, it would be necessary that the licensing of this software complies with the licenses of all components, which would require compliance with the (A)GPL-3.0.

That means if your Apache-2.0 component can only be used together with an (A)GPL-3.0 component, **the practical effect is that the resulting software will have to comply with (A)GPL-3.0 conditions, *as if* your library had been entirely (A)GPL-3.0 licensed.**

While it is probably fine if your library stays under Apache-2.0 terms, this might be confusing to some users of the library.

A few notes on related licenses:

- LGPL limits the reach of the “copyleft” conditions to the LGPL-covered component itself, which makes it easier to combine components under various licenses.
- (A)GPL-2.0-only is not compatible with Apache-2.0. It is not possible to combine a GPL-2.0-only component and an Apache-2.0 component into a single program, because these licenses have terms that contradict each other.

Notes in case you are the copyright holder for the (A)GPL-3.0 library:

- If you are the sole copyright holder for the library, you can change its license to Apache-2.0, if you want. But it's important to consider what your specific licensing goals are – why did you choose (A)GPL-3.0 to start with, and why would you be OK with offering this functionality under Apache-2.0 instead?
- If you are only interested in sharing certain parts between the two libraries, it may be possible to extract them into a third library that you license under a permissive license such as Apache-2.0. But again, this only works if you're the copyright holder for those parts.

Comment: Can I grant my own Apache library an "exception" from the GPL license?

Comment: @ZihengWang That doesn't quite work as you expect. Open source license give rights to recipients of the software, including the right to modify the software how they want. If you give users of the Apache-covered library the right to use your GPL-covered library without having to comply with GPL terms, then in effect you would have relicensed the GPL library to Apache-2.0. But there's a bit more nuance here. Perhaps you want the LGPL license. It might also be possible to provide additional permissions to users of a particular version of your Apache-covered library, but that gets tricky quickly.